# How to set default select of RadioGroup in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MCQ Select using `RadioGroup` in my code. Once the user selects and submits the value he should be able to come back and see the option he has selected.
(Like google Forms where I can come back and see the option I selected before highlighted.)

Here is my code :

```
<FormControl component="fieldset">
    <RadioGroup onChange={(event)=>{formData.KPI_5_S = event.target.value}} aria-label="status" name="row-radio-buttons-group">
        <FormControlLabel value="Finished with respect to requirements" control={<Radio />} label="Finished with respect to requirements" />
        <FormControlLabel value="In progress" control={<Radio />} label="In progress" />
        <FormControlLabel value="Yet to start" control={<Radio />} label="Yet to start" />
        <FormControlLabel value="Failed to get the expected result" control={<Radio />} label="Failed to get the expected result" />
    </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

How do I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `defaultValue` in the `RadioGroup`. See the full API of `RadioGroup` [here](https://mui.com/api/radio-group/). The default value is one of the value prop of the `Radio` inside:

```
<FormControl component="fieldset">
    <RadioGroup defaultValue="In progress" {...}>
        <FormControlLabel value="Finished with respect to requirements" control={<Radio />} label="Finished with respect to requirements" />
        <FormControlLabel value="In progress" control={<Radio />} label="In progress" />
        <FormControlLabel value="Yet to start" control={<Radio />} label="Yet to start" />
        <FormControlLabel value="Failed to get the expected result" control={<Radio />} label="Failed to get the expected result" />
    </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```